# Array Doubling Size Strategies

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis, arrays, stacks

I would like to discuss resizing strategies for arrays please. If you have an array of $k$ initial size and it gets full, so you would like to choose from one of the following approaches:

**Approach 1**: if array get full, then we resize the array by $k$ constant.
**Approach 2**: if array get full, then we resize the array by doubling the previous size.
**Approach 3**: if array get full, then we follow $3k, 5k, 7k, 9k, \cdots$ etc resizing.

Now to compare approaches:

1. **Approach 1** is time consuming as we do resizing more frequently.
2. **Approach 2** is memory consuming.
3. **Approach 3** is most intuitive one because it adopts to higher frequency of PUSH calls.

**Problem**: How approach 3 is more intuitive compared to approach 2 please? Both are similar as I see them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [amortized analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis). Note that usually array resizing requires (1) get memory for new version, (2) copy old contents over, (3) delete old version. The point of your approach 2 (double the size of the array each time, more generally extend by a fixed factor) is that it gives amortized constant cost for each push on the stack. The others get costlier when the stack grows.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very clear. But my question please is to why the solution I got above says that Approach 3 is most intuitive one because it adopts to higher frequency of PUSH calls? What does that mean?

Comment: @Aura, the problem with approach 2 is that every so often the whole process grinds to a halt while stuff gets copied over (the individual cost of a push varies wildly). In any case, an individual push can be quite cheap (a few memory accesses) or very costly (need to extend --i.e., copy-- a huge stack). It very much matters what you want to prefer: if throughput use approach 2, if latency use some other --costlier on average, less variable cost-- data structure/algorithm.